# Import all folders and related files

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

If I have the Main folder in which there is Folder 1 (with File 1 inside), Folder 2 (with File 2 inside), Folder 3 (with File 3 inside), is there a way to import all folders and their sub-files  at the same time?

```
Main
> Folder 1 >> File 1
> Folder 2 >> File 2
> Folder 3 >> File 3
```

I just tried `import Main` or `from Main import *`, but it doesn't work

I don't want to write like this, because I have so many folders (20) and I would stretch the code:

```
import Main.Folder1
import Main.Folder2
import Main.Folder3
```

Comment: Did you try adding an `__init__.py` in the `Main` folder and import all the submodules?

Comment: @Paul Rooney I have not tried. Could you show me how to do with an answer please? I am not using a class. Thank you

Comment: Look at some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for). Also the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules) may help.

Comment: @Paul Rooney You're kind, thanks, but I'm new to Python. I have read, but understand little of these things. Can you show me how I can use it in an answer relevant to my case? You would really help me a lot. I will be happy to accept your answer as a solution in case you help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the root folder where your folder 1, folder 2, and folder 3 are present. Sample code snippet shown below:

```
import os

dirname = '/root/directory'
folder_list = os.listdir(dirname)
```

And once you have a list of directories you can loop over the directory and read the files that are of interest. The sample code snippet is shown below:

```
import glob
modules = glob.glob('<directory_to_loop>/*.py')
```

The above code will read all the python files available in the directory.

Comment: Not what I am looking for. I  get errors. Your code makes me specify the main folder in "dirname" first, then I would like to import folder 1, folder 2 and folder 2 at the same time, but your code makes me specify the directory to repeat: in my case there are others too 3 subfolders

Comment: FOR THE READERS: I still need help. I have not solved with the kind response of the user. Can you help me? Thank you